# Prevent double space when entering username

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, space

When users register to my website I want to allow them to use spaces in their username, but only one space per word.

My current code:

```
$usor = $_POST['usernameone'];
$allowed = "/[^a-z0-9 ]/i";
$username = preg_replace($allowed,"",$usor);
$firstlettercheck = $username[0];
$lastlettercheck = substr("$username", -1);

if ($firstlettercheck == " " or $lastlettercheck == " ")
{
echo "Usernames can not contain a space at start/end of username."; 
}
```

What do I need to add to ensure there is only one space entered inebtween words of the username?

Comment: You should choose between warn the user and perform an automatic correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex of `(^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$)` to validate using [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
if (preg_match('/(^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$)/', $username)) {
    echo "Usernames can not contain a space at start/end of username and can't contain double spacing."; 
}
```

[**REGEX DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/iB4dI1)

**Autopsy**:

- `(^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$)`:

  - `^\s+` *matches 1 or more white-space characters (space/tab/newline) in the start of the string*
  - `|` *OR:*
  - `\s{2,}` *matches 2 or more white-space characters (space/tab/newline) anywhere in the string*
  - `|` *OR:*
  - `\s+$` *matches 1 or more white-space characters (space/tab/newline) in the end of the string*

If you wish to test them separately instead:

```
if (preg_match('/(^\s+|\s+$)/', $username)) {
    echo 'Usernames can not contain a space at start/end of username.'; 
} else if (preg_match('/\s{2,}/', $username)) {
    echo 'Usernames can not contain double spacing.';
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Smith The regex does that. Check out the demo if you wish. He never mentioned stripping, but rather giving an error.

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me what each part in '/(^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$)/' is? Would be greatful

Comment: @StevenWilmot I've added an autopsy for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$username = preg_replace('/[\s]+', " ", $usor);
```

That will replace multiple spaces with a single space.

Comment: The user would then have a username they didn't ask for, and wouldn't be able to log in.

Comment: But this is what the OP asked for